# Array of objects with some objects containing another array, need to filter it by values within the object containing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Sorry for the long title question didn't know how to properly formulate my question.

So this is the question, I got an array which stores objects, and within those objects there's another array with the key tags and which is an array that gets filled with tags.

Object:

```
var arr = new Array;

arr[0] = {
            "like": 0,
            "dislike": 0,
            "answer": "body",
            "tags" : ["offline", "facebook"],
            "comments" : []
        };

arr[1] = {
            "like": 0,
            "dislike": 0,
            "answer": "body",
            "tags" : ["school", "online"],
            "comments" : []
        };

arr[2] = {
        "like": 0,
        "dislike": 0,
        "answer": "body",
        "tags" : ["school", "offline"],
        "comments" : []
    };
```

The [0], [1] indexes respresent and ID, but that isn't really important here.

The problem is when I try to filter it with(I know it only tries to filter arr[0] atm but I will write a loop so it goes through all the indexes):

```
var toFind = "offline";

var filtered = arr[0].filter(function(el) {
  return el.tags === toFind;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

It says arr[0].filter is not a function, but got no idea why it thinks arr[0] should be taken into account as a function.

When I remove the [0] it gives back a blank array...

So my question is how can I get the .filter function to give back the complete object based on tags in the tags array. So that if I search for the tag "school" it gives back arr[1] and arr[2], the complete objects.

Hope I my question is crystal clear and that I provided enough information. If you guys need anymore information, feel free to ask me for it. Or if you want me to clarify things, just ask :)

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: `arr.filter(x => x.tags.includes(toFind))`

Comment: the Object.prototype doesn't have a filter() method, which is what you are accessing with arr[0]. You just want to filter the arr itself

Comment: Thank you guys it works now thanks to all the quick replies! I used dgeare's solution! It works wonders :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like has been said, arr[0] points to an object, which doesn't have a filter method. You need to call filter on the array itself

```js
var tagToFind = "school";
var arr = new Array;

arr[0] = {
            "like": 0,
            "dislike": 0,
            "answer": "body",
            "tags" : ["offline", "facebook"],
            "comments" : []
        };

arr[1] = {
            "like": 0,
            "dislike": 0,
            "answer": "body",
            "tags" : ["school", "online"],
            "comments" : []
        };

arr[2] = {
        "like": 0,
        "dislike": 0,
        "answer": "body",
        "tags" : ["school", "offline"],
        "comments" : []
    };

var filtered = arr.filter(function(item){
  return item.tags && //to account for undefined tags properties
    item.tags.includes(tagToFind); //if you're supporting IE you will need to look and check each element instead
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: @DennisJansen Welcome. Happy to help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the documention : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control

you shall use :

```
var arr = new Array;

arr[0] = {
            "like": 0,
            "dislike": 0,
            "answer": "body",
            "tags" : ["offline", "facebook"],
            "comments" : []
        };


var toFind = "offline";
//I'm filtering on arr[0].tags directly !! 
var filtered = arr[0].tags.filter(function(el) { 

  return el === toFind;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply man! It worked but it only gave back "offline" I needed the whole object. Nonetheless thanks for the quick reply, really appreciated. Dgeare's solution works wonders for me, doesn't even need to use a loop through loop through all indexes :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, it appears that you want something along the lines of

```
arr.forEach((a) => {
    if (a["tags"].includes(toFind))
        console.log(a);
});
```

This will loop through each element of `arr` and check that the `tags` array contains `toFind` (and prints out the object if it does).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it for the whole array then try this

```
 var arr = new Array;
 arr[0] = {
        "like": 0,
        "dislike": 0,
        "answer": "body",
        "tags" : ["offline", "facebook"],
        "comments" : []
    };

  arr[1] = {
        "like": 0,
        "dislike": 0,
        "answer": "body",
        "tags" : ["school", "online"],
        "comments" : []
    };

   arr[2] = {
    "like": 0,
    "dislike": 0,
    "answer": "body",
    "tags" : ["school", "offline"],
    "comments" : []
};
var filtered = arr.filter(function(el) {
  return el.tags.find(function (entity){
    return entity===toFind;
  });
});

 console.log(filtered);
```